# Вопрос с задачей ЯП C

Tags: c, циклы

Я только начал изучать программирование. Попалась задача:

> *Напишите программу, которая создает два восьмиэлементных массива типа double и использует цикл для ввода значений восьми элементов первого массива. Программа должна накапливать в элементах второго массива суммы первого массива с нарастающим итогом. Например, четвертый элемент второго массива должен быть равен сумме первых четырех элементов первого массива, а пятый элемент второго массива - сумме пяти первых элементов первого массива. (Это можно сделать с помощью вложенных циклов, однако если учесть тот факт, что пятый элемент второго массива равен четвертому элементу второго массива плюс пятый элемент первого массива, можно избежать вложенных циклов и применить для решения задачи единственный цикл.) В завершение воспользуйтесь циклом для вывода содержимого обоих массивов, при этом первый массив должен отображаться в первой строке, а каждый элемент второго массива должен помещаться непосредственно под соответствующим элементом первого массива.*

Вот код выполнения:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
const int size=8;
double mass1[size],mass2[size],mass3[size];
int i,j;
 //первый массив
for(i=0;i<size;i++) //ввод значений пользователем в первый массив
{
    printf("Give me %d num: ",i+1);
    scanf("%lf",&mass1[i]);
}
//второй массив
//создание второго массива без помощи встроенного цикла
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    mass2[i]=mass1[i]+mass2[i-1];
}
//создание второго массива методом вложенного цикла
//для этого создам еще 1 массив, для удобства вывода
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    for(j=i;j>=0;j--)
    {
        mass3[i]+=mass1[j];
    }

}
//нужен один цикл для вывода всех массивов
//сделаю несколько т.к. не знаю пока как все сделать через 1 цилк
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%.1lf |",mass1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%.1lf |",mass2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%.1lf |",mass3[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
return 0;
```

}

Вопрос №1 - вывод второго массива время от времени багается(появляется миллион цифр) - я предполагаю что выражение: mass2[i]=mass1[i]+mass2[i-1]; cодержит ошибку т.к. неизвестно значение mass2[i-1] при i = 0.
Собственно я никак не могу понять как мне правильно сделать этот цикл, чтобы он корректно вычислял по следующей схеме: mass2[i]=mass1[i]+mass2[i-1], но вычислял корректно при i=0.

Вопрос №2. Как мне сделать вывод обоих массивов, при котором элементы второго массива выводятся под соответсвующими порядку элементами первого массива, через printf() используя 1 цикл(можно вложенный)

Стоит отметить, т.к. эта задача из учебника Стивена Прата(глава 6 упражнение 14) здесь можно использовать циклы while, do while, for и простые функции.

Comment: безусловно ошибка тут есть. Цикл надо с 1 начинать. А 0 элемент просто равен 0 из другого массива.

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли!